# Laravel 5.5 API Request Validation

Tags: laravel, validation, request

I'm trying to validate an incoming Post request but when the request not pass de validation laravel shows the welcome view and i don't know why.

This is the code that i'm using:

Simple Route:

```
Route::post('products', 'ProductController@index');
```

In Controller:

```
public function index(Request $request) {

        $this->NullRequest($request);

        $product = Product::paginate(15);

        return ProductResource::collection($product);

    }

public function NullRequest(Request $request){

        $request->validate([

            'merchant_id' =>'required', //101
            'api_user' =>'required', //102
            'barcode' =>'required', //103
            'reader_name' =>'required', //104
            'branch' =>'required', //105
            'trx_type' =>'required', //106 
            'secret_key' =>'required', //107
            'timestamp' =>'required', //108
            'created_at' =>'required', //109
            'access_token' =>'required', //110


        ]);

    }
```

And this is a portion of custom validation error (validation.php)

```
'custom' => [
        /*'attribute-name' => [
            'rule-name' => 'custom-message',
        ],*/

        'merchant_id' => [
            'required' => $responseCodes->responseList('1', '101'),
        ],

        'api_user' => [
            'required' => $responseCodes->responseList('1', '102'),
        ],

        'barcode' => [
            'required' => $responseCodes->responseList('1', '103'),
        ],
].
```

I have a class dedicate to handle my response Codes, so $responseCodes is an instance of that class.
If request it's ok all works fine, but if not laravel shows default welcome view.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why are you not using Laravel's default validation

Comment: hi! thanks for reply... i need an specific response code, so i created a class to handle them. 
For example, i need differents messages for required depending on each field. 
I have a lot of responses codes clasified in categories and subcategories.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i solved this problem... the solution was so "stupid"...
In my basic php client, i was sending accept => application/json in header inside the $header (using curl).
When test this request using postman fail and the reason was that i omitted add accept => application/json in header.